# Prove: $\cos^2 x (\sec x - 1)(\sec x + 1) = (1 - \cos x)(1 + \cos x)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove the trigonometric identity
>   $$\cos^2 x (\sec x - 1)(\sec x + 1) = (1 - \cos x)(1 + \cos x)$$

I've searched high and low on the net and cannot find identities where there is $+$ or $- 1$'s in the equation. Any help is appreciated.

Edit after reviewing comments.
$\cos^2 {x} (\sec {x} -1)(\sec {x} +1) = (1 - \cos {x})(1 + \cos {x})\quad$
$\cos^2 {x} (\sec^2 {x}- 1) = 1 - \cos^2 {x}\quad$
$\cos^2 {x}·tan^2 {x} = \sin^2 {x} \quad$
$\cos^2 {x} ·\frac{\sin^2 {x}}{\cos^2 {x}} = \sin^2 {x} \quad$
$\frac{\sin^2 {x}}{\cos^2 {x} }=\frac{\sin^2 {x}}{\cos^2 {x} }\quad$

How's that? I tried the $\sec {x }= \frac1{\cos {x}}\quad$ method.    However I was unsuccessful.

Comment: HINT use :  $$\sec x=1/\cos x$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hint**: $(\sec x -1)(\sec x + 1) = \sec^2 x - 1 = \tan^2 x = \dfrac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}$, and $(1-\cos x)(1+ \cos x) = 1 - \cos^2 x = \sin^2 x$. I hope you can pull it off...

Comment: Excellent hint. I was able to verify the equation really fast.

Comment: So trigonometric identities can be multiplied out like normal brackets then, is that how they work?
(sec x - 1)(sec x + 1) = sec^2 x + sec x - sec x - 1 = sec^2 x -1... Correctly done?
Still working out the rest. I need to review this chapter thoroughly when i'm not so under the pump

Comment: (1 − cos x)(1 + cos x) = 1 + cos x - cos x - cos^2 x = 1 - cos^2 x.... Yes?

Comment: -1. A lot of unecessary steps. We can simply multiply cosx in each bracket of the lhs.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $\frac1{\cos{x}}\;$ for $\sec{x}\;$ in the identity, and it will shout its truth to you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$c(\frac1c-1)c(\frac1c+1)$$

Comment: Trivial, isn't it ?